# two processes are listed for one shellscript?

Tags: bash, ps, sh

I have a shell script which does somewhat simple.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
do something boring...
```

When I execute the shell script like this,

```bsh
$ nohup sh mysh.sh > /null/dev/ 2>&1 &
```

I see there are two processes listed.

```bsh
$ ps -ef | grep mysh
... xxxxx 1     ... sh mysh.sh // same xxxxx
... yyyyy xxxxx ... sh mysh.sh // same xxxxx
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

I just recreated what you have here and replaced `do something boring...` with `sleep 10000` and did not have this happen. I believe that you are doing something which uses fork() or clone() to create a child process. I had suspected that nohup ran the process as a child process but that does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, yyyyy is the child process of xxxxx. It is perfectly normal that the same shell script be executed inside "mysh.sh" which will result in such a scenario.

Are you directly/indirectly invoking mysh.sh inside the script? That's the only way I could think this will ever happen.